# JFrame and while loop

Tags: java

How do I break a while loop if I click on my jframe shutdown? I 'm making a clicker that needs to be stopped at some point, but it'll just continue clicking even tho the exit has been pressed.

```
public class ClickWindow {

private JFrame frame;
private static Clicker click;
private static long currTime;
private static long totalTime;
private JTextField textField;
private static int textFieldValue = 0;
private static Boolean Bool = true;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    click = new Clicker();

    ClickWindow window = new ClickWindow();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ClickWindow() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 289, 90);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Press Space");
    btnNewButton_1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                Bool = false;
            }

            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {

                    if(textFieldValue == 0){
                        textFieldValue = 250;
                    }
                try {

                    while (Bool) {
                        click.click();
                        textFieldValue = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                        Thread.sleep(textFieldValue);
                    }
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(10, 25, 110, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);     
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(127, 25, 141, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
    Bool = false;
}
}
```

Clicker class

```
public class Clicker{

public static void click() throws AWTException{

    Robot bot = new Robot();        
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
}
```

Edited with the full code.

Comment: What do you mean the loop prevents you from shutting down your application? Is your loop running on the EDT?

Comment: Yes it looks like your EDT gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: Try to instantiate your ClickWindow outside the invokeLater() method

Comment: @user2651804 just tried, did not work.

Comment: You have a loop on the EDT which makes your GUI unresponsive, you need to run the loop on a new thread.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you can close the window properly, unless you press space to start a loop? And does the Enter key properly stop the loop?

Comment: If I haven't started the loop I can close it yes. And the enter key does not stop it, unfortunately!

Comment: That is to be expected, that's good. In this case, try posting the code you said didn't work after you put `new ClickWindow()` outside of `invokeLater()`

Comment: Done. Is it that simple or am I just boiling? I updated my post with it.

Comment: I can't immediately see what the problem is if this doesn't work.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around it either. Just missing this one part, and the program is done. But thanks for help!

Comment: Oh. It's because the keyListener is run on EDT too.. :) I will try to post an answer that solves it.

Comment: It's not necessary, I made a suitable fix by getting x coordinate of my mouse, and stop the loop if the x coordinate are less than 10. :) It'll work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should define the defaultCloseOperation for your JFrame:

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

If you set the defaultCloseOperation, hitting the close button will trigger a call to `System exit`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                 JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
                 myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 //...add components here
                 myFrame.pack();
                 myFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried that but with no luck. The jframe is in my main class if that matter tho.

Comment: @JonCode: did you start your JFrame properly? I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I tried it yes, I updated my post with the code. But no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shutdown the entire application you can just do this:

```
jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

This will shutdown your application after the `Jframe` was closed.

You can also call `System.exit(0)` in your `windowClosing` method or whenever you want to shutdown your application

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding the keyListener to your `JButton` try having your JFrame, i.e. ClickWindow implement it. I think this would work.

Comment: I updated my post. Should be clear what I'm trying to do now.